# XSLT or statement not working properly

Tags: xslt

I'm having issues with this test in xslt

```
<xsl:if test="(count(dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row) == 0) or (dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[1]/@Process != '')">
    <textarea>
         ....
    </textarea>
</xsl:if>
```

I'd like to allow the textarea to be displayed if

- count(dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row) == 0
- OR if the Process attribute of the first row is empty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

== is not a valid XPath operator. For testing equality, just use =.

```
<xsl:if test="(count(dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row) = 0) or (dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[1]/@Process != '')">
    <textarea>
         ....
    </textarea>
</xsl:if>
```